# Restricting a certain individual with Editor permissions from seeing data entered by others in a shared Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a scenario where a fixed number of individuals (say 4-5) will be entering data to the same Google Sheet. So basically I will be the owner of the Google Sheet and will be sharing it with 4-5 individuals. What I need is; a certain individual A should only see data entered by him and not by rest of the individuals. How can I achieve this? All the individuals will need to enter their data to this sheet so all of them will have 'Editor' permissions. But then a specific individual A should not have access to what others are entering. It's ok if A can see data entered by himself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this issue is recommended to be handled by series of IMPORTRANGEs and individual spreadsheets for each person where you as "administrator" will gather data from each minion into your master spreadsheet. this way no one will get access to sensitive data apart from you. in case there is a subset of the dataset you need to share you can export it into each spreadsheet from your master sheet.